# How to assign the next consecutive number?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In my business logic, when I pass to accepted an invoice, I need to assign the next consecutive number as reference, but I have doubts how I should to do that.

Perhaps I could have a table in the database with the last number used, with concurrency control, something like that:

```
InvoicesCounter(LastNumber, Timestamp)
```

it has only one row, with a timestamp field for the concurrency, so in my application layer I could do something like that:

I was thinking something like that:

```
MyAplicationLayerMethod()
{
    Invoce myInvoiceToAccept = _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.GetInvoid(1);
    InvoiceCounter myInvoiceCounter = _unitOfWork.InvoiceCounter.GetLastNumber();
    
    myInvoiceToAccept.Accept(myLastNumber);
    myInvoiceCounter.Increment();

    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Or perhaps to have a service in the domain that pass the invoice to accepted and increment the counter:

```
MyAplicationLayerMethod()
{
    Invoce myInvoiceToAccept = _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.GetInvoid(1);
    InvoiceCounter myInvoiceCounter = _unitOfWork.InvoiceCounter.GetLastNumber();
    
    InvoiceServiceAccept(myInvoiceToAccept, myInvoiceCounter);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();        
}

class MyDomainInvoceSericeAccept
{
    static void AcceptInvoce(Inovce paramInvoce, InvoceCounter paramInvoceCounter)
    {
         paramInvoce.Accept();
         paramIvoceCounter.Increment();
    }
}
```

Or perhaps neither of them and there is a better option?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the goal to assign incrementing id-numbers to the invoices? If so, just let the database do it, If you use a sequential key and leave the id as zero, the db will do the id assignment.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks for the suggestion, but if I am not wrong, Sql Server doesn't ensure that it will assign the next incremental number. At least, when I use autoincrement as indentity in a key bigint, sometimes i get gaps between IDs. Anyway, I need to know the consecutive number to create the final invoice number, that has some extra character, but the base count is a number and from this number, I would create the final code.

Comment: Your requirements does not make much sense to me. Say that you have some way to assign each invoice a consecutive id, but the database commit for one of the invoices fails, or the invoice is removed, or something else occurs. Now the IDs will no longer be consecutive. While you can use a database for concurrency control, I'm not sure what you mean by Timestamp. An actual timestamp will not work, and the timestamp concurrency method is called "rowversion" in SQL server.

Comment: An invoice that has a number assigned, can´t be deleted. If the commit to assign the number fails, then no matter, I try again to get the new number. So never I will have a gap. My idea with OrderCounter it was to control in some way if someone add a new invoice since I read the data to create a new invoice, I get the las number from this table and I finally commint the new order.

Comment: Database identity columns work they way they do for performance reasons. Particularly for lock contention and high availability scenarios. If you don't expect to ever allocate thousands of ids a second, on multiple servers, then you can build your own solution with an `insert ... select max(id)+1, ...` and a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 3 ways to assign a number without gaps:

1. Serialize all invoice writes to ensure they can't happen concurrently (e.g. serializable isolation level).
2. Assign the number asynchronously (after invoices are created & committed) by a single threaded process, thus no concurrency.
3. Use optimistic concurrency with retries. Put a unique constraint on `invoice_number`. When attempting to write, fetch the last committed number & increment. If you get a unique constraint violation then try again. This could be quite expensive if you have lots of contention obviously.

Note that `invoiceRepository.nextNumber()` could be acceptable, just like we'd do for DB-generated IDs.

Most importantly however, the requirement seems quite fishy. Why would it matter if they were gaps in the sequence? It's quite costly to ensure a no-gap sequence and adds complexity, are you sure the business can't live with an occasional break in the sequence and that it's not an artificial requirement?

Comment: Yes, at least in Spain, the invoice has to be consecutive with no gaps. So if some invoice is incorrect, you can't delete it, you have to do a corrective invoice to correct the wrong one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Ok, then I don't think you have other options than what I suggested. Gapless requires no concurrency.